# how to include a css-hidden input field in forms

Tags: css

I want to include a css-hidden input field in forms and check if the hidden field has it’s value filled out then reject the submission

Answer (score 2):

Brief tutorial: [Fighting Spam with CSS](http://www.modernblue.com/web-design-blog/fighting-spam-with-css/)

A more comprehensive article on the subject: [Stopping spambots with hashes and honeypots](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && strlen($_POST['hidden_field']))
{
  // proceed with submission
}
else
{
  // reject because hidden field does not contain any value.
}
```